# Is there any SE Site where Questions related to Hacking are on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there any SE Site where we can post questions related to Hacking (Networking)?

Comment: What is "hacking (networking)"?

Comment: You need to be much more specific and expand on the _exact_ meaning of "hacking (networking)". Is this in a programming context? Social context? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IT Security - Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) is *probably* what you are looking for. From the [FAQ](https://security.stackexchange.com/):

> ### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> IT Security - Stack Exchange is for Information Security professionals to discuss protecting **assets** from **threats** and **vulnerabilities**. Topics include, but are not limited to:
>
> - web app hardening
> - network security
> - social engineering, including phishing
> - risk management
> - policies
> - penetration testing
> - security tools
> - using cryptography
> - incident response

However notice that the FAQ explicitly mentions "protecting assets" and that the closest on topic item to Hacking (Networking) is "network security", so if what you are aiming for is malicious, please take it somewhere else (and by that I mean outside Stack Exchange). Before you post on IT Security make sure you read their FAQ thoroughly (twice), and it wouldn't hurt if you dropped in by their [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) to verify that your question would be welcomed by the community.

If you are more interested in cryptography and cryptographic algorithms, then you should also check out [Crypto - Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't see "hacking (networking)" on that list, so I remain unconvinced.

Comment: @the Second item on the list is "network security" and the next one is "social engineering, including phishing".